# Installing SSL certificate manually in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, installation, directory, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have recently generated my SSL certificate and I have a recieved a zip file. And I am bit lost how to install it manually in PHPmyAdmin. With no clue to upload directory.

Please help.

I have tried using on file manager didn't help. There is phpmyadmin panel.. no resources to help.

Comment: If you are talking about the ability to access your phpMyAdmin via HTTPS - then that would require installing it on the web server, not phpMyAdmin itself.